# Setting array references equal jasmin assembler

Tags: compiler-construction, jvm, jasmin

I am having some problems figuring out how to assign to arrays equal to each other in jasmine. I wish to compile code like the following

```
array a[1];
array b[1];

a = b;
```

Now I want an actual copy of b not assigning them to the same thing.  Suppose a is in register `0` and b is in register `1`

then the following is what I thought would work

```
aload   1
astore  0
```

but in fact now if I change b then a will also change.  How would I do this in jasmin so that the arrays are distinct e.g.

```
array a[1];
array b[1];
a[1] = 'a';
b[1] = 'b';
a = b;
b[1] = 'a';
print a; //should print 'b' but prints 'a' currently
print b; //should print 'a' and does currently
```

Note the code that I have written is correct java, however, this is for a different language.

Comment: "now if I change b then a will also change" That would also be true in Java.

Comment: Yes I know I this language is different,  I am just compiling for the java virtual machine. In fact, I just compiled the code that I outputted and it is the exact same as the java compilers output, which is, in fact, that problem.  Since I am trying to do something difforent. @sepp2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about Jasmin or bytecode at all.

If you want to copy *the contents* of the array, call [`Object.clone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) with [`invokevirtual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual) instruction or [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) / [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) with [`invokestatic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokestatic).